# Unable to automate a change of contact's device status with API in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, contact, update, mobilepush

We are trying to find a way to automate a change of a contact's device Status in MobilePush demographics in the Marketing Cloud. Theoretically, this should be possible with the [Update contacts call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updateContacts.htm) in MC API (it is possible to change it manually in the Contact Builder but that's not really feasible for us).

I am calling the Update contacts API but it doesn't work, nothing happens in MC. I get operationStatus OK and 0 rowsAffected without any errors (testing with Postman, see the request and response below). I tried to change the Status to Inactive by setting the value to both the values 2 (as an Integer) and "2" (as a String), same response. It's called as a PATCH method with the correct domain, I set the correct content-type and the bearer token (all double checked). In the request body, I supply the correct contact key and device ID from All Contacts in the Contact Builder (the device is currently Active).

Am I setting incorrect values or is there something else I am missing? If there is another way to automate this use case, I would be also open to it.

My request:

```
{
    "contactKey": "myContactKey",
    "attributeSets": [
    {
        "name": "MobilePush Demographics",
            "items": [{
                "values": [
                {
                    "name": "Device ID",
                    "value": "myDeviceID"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Status",
                    "value": "2"
                }]
            }]
    }
    ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "operationStatus": "OK",
    "rowsAffected": 0,
    "contactKey": "myContactKey",
    "contactID": 123456789,
    "contactTypeID": 0,
    "isNewContactKey": false,
    "requestServiceMessageID": "0ecb1697-1db6-48cd-b538-d80262e47b77",
    "responseDateTime": "2020-07-03T04:21:20.278043-06:00",
    "hasErrors": false,
    "resultMessages": [],
    "serviceMessageID": "1b86d736-8b62-467d-a9d5-3e0bb8e28fd6"
}
```

**EDIT**: MC Support told me that the Status field has 3 states. But didn't explain why nothing happens.

1= Active
2= Inactive
3= Deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Application" parameter for the values of MobilePush Demographics is also required.

The request should look like this:

```
{
    "contactKey": "myContactKey",
    "attributeSets": [{
        "name": "MobilePush Demographics",
            "items": [{
                "values": [
                {
                    "name": "Device ID",
                    "value": "myDeviceID"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Application",
                    "value": "myApplicationID"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Status",
                    "value": "2"
                }]
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```